# Update specific properties in specific object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just get little stuck on quite simple task. Apologise in advance if this question is already answered. I just can not find it. I got objects in state

```
    state = {
    controls: {
        email: {
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'email'
            },
            placeholder: 'Email Address',
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                isEmail: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false,
            errorMsg: ""
        },
        password: {
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'password'
            },
            placeholder: 'Password',
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 6
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false,
            errorMsg: ""
        }
    },
};
```

and I need to update "touched" to true and "errorMsg" to a text only if "valid" in the object equal to false

I managed to filter all object keys with "valid" value equal to false

```
const invalidInputs = Object.keys(this.state.controls).filter(key => {
        return this.state.controls[key].valid === false
      })
```

Now I need to loop through each "invalidInputs" and update touched to true and "errorMsg" to a specific text. I have tried

```
  for (let key in invalidInputs){
        const updatedControl = {
            ...this.state.controls,
            [invalidInputs[key]]: {
                ...this.state.controls[invalidInputs[key]],
                touched: true,
                errorMsg: errorMsg(this.state.controls[invalidInputs[key]].validation, this.state.controls[invalidInputs[key]].value)
            }
        };
        this.setState({controls:updatedControl})
        console.log(updatedControl)
      }
```

but that doesn't work obviously. Can anyone give me some nice solution or direct me to an answer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want only the filtered `controls` after as result of all?

Comment: No I wanted to update properties in the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post a solution which works for me which is the same as the first solution but without mutating state

```
const updatedControls = { ...this.state.controls }

    for (let keys in updatedControls) {
        if (updatedControls[keys].valid === false) {
            const control = updatedControls[keys]
            control.errorMsg = "new msg"
            control.touched = true

            updatedControls[keys] = control
        }
    }
    this.setState({ controls: updatedControls })
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `for..in` to loop through the object and check the value of `valid`

```js
let state = {
  controls: {
    email: {
      elementConfig: {
        type: 'email'
      },
      placeholder: 'Email Address',
      value: '',
      validation: {
        required: true,
        isEmail: true
      },
      valid: false,
      touched: false,
      errorMsg: ""
    },
    password: {
      elementConfig: {
        type: 'password'
      },
      placeholder: 'Password',
      value: '',
      validation: {
        required: true,
        minLength: 6
      },
      valid: false,
      touched: false,
      errorMsg: ""
    }
  },
};

for (let keys in state.controls) {
  if (!state.controls[keys].valid) {
    state.controls[keys].errorMsg = 'New Msg';
    state.controls[keys].touched = true;
  }
}

console.log(state)
```

Comment: Thanks man...That is what I needed and I don't understand where did I get lost. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` and change the object according to needs instead of using `filter()`.

```js
let state = {
    controls: {
        email: {
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'email'
            },
            placeholder: 'Email Address',
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                isEmail: true
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false,
            errorMsg: ""
        },
        password: {
            elementConfig: {
                type: 'password'
            },
            placeholder: 'Password',
            value: '',
            validation: {
                required: true,
                minLength: 6
            },
            valid: false,
            touched: false,
            errorMsg: ""
        }
    },
};
let result = Object.keys(state.controls)
                   .map((con) => (!state.controls[con].valid ?
                   ({...state.controls[con],errorMsg:"New msg",touched:true}) :
                   ({...state.controls[con],touched:true})))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Maheer Ali for this solution too... But the first solution is more decent.

Comment: @ptr.chov yes it is. But take care it will mutate the original object

Comment: Yeah in particular immutable state is desired in React

Comment: Hi @Maheer Ali I tried it your way but unfortunately variable "result" return an array of objects which then when I update state with it setState({controls:result}) alter original objects into an array. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: @ptr.chov Why you don't use brk method?

Comment: @Maheer Ali can you please specify what did you mean by brk method?

Comment: The other answer to your question. Which has 4 upvotes